# OpenISO8583.Net BCD Formatted Message Type

Tags: customization, iso8583, openiso8583.net

I am learning how to use the OpenISO8583.Net code. I have derived a new ISO8583 class from the original one. One of the differences in my new class is that the Message Type field is going to be [Numeric, BCD]; so I wrote this as part of the class contructor (I do have a custom DefaultTemplate declared as part of the class):

```
DefaultTemplate.MsgTypeFormatter = Formatters.Bcd;
```

I created a new message with a message type of 0100 (MsgType._0100_AUTH_REQ). Without assigning any other bits.

```
        FDISO8583 fdISO8583 = new FDISO8583();
        fdISO8583.MessageType = FDISO8583.MsgType._0100_AUTH_REQ;
        byte[] testMsg = fdISO8583.ToMsg();
```

My ending result byte array is: 01-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00 which I think is correct. First 2 bytes for the message type with the BCD value and the bitmap is all zeroes.

Now the problem is when I test unpacking it. Using:

```
        fdISO8583 = new FDISO8583();
        int pos = fdISO8583.Unpack(testMsg, 0);
```

The resulting message type gets a value of zero.

I need help understanding if this is a problem on the way I defined the class or a bug in the ISO8583 code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have indeed found a bug.  I logged it as Issue 13 and have fixed it.  I have release version 0.5.2 on nuget and uploaded the bin file to the googlecode project.